# Почему в FireFox попап возникает под основным окном?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, firefox, reactjs, popup

Приложение на React и Material UI. Авторизация через ВКонтакте – по нажатию на кнопку вызывается метод [`VK.Auth.login()`](https://vk.com/dev/openapi_auth) – и открывает новое окно-попап с ВК.

**Проблема**: в FireFox этот попап почему-то возникает *под* основным окном с кнопкой, и его не видно. Если повесить этот же метод `VK.Auth.login` просто в обработчик `click` на обычной ссылке, безо всяких React'ов, попап возникает поверх окна, как и ожидается. В Chrome такой проблемы нет – попап всегда поверх.

Как в варианте с React сделать, чтобы попап появлялся над основным окном?

**Upd.** решить проблему помогло обёртывание в `setTimeout( () => { VK.Auth.login..}, 0)`. Остался вопрос «Почему?!»